# ASP.Net Multiple update panels updating when they are not supposed to

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

I have some Update Panels on a webpage all set to UpdateMode="Conditional", however when the AsyncPostBackTrigger on one of the Update Panels is triggered, all of the Update Panels refresh.

The following is one of the update panel HTML markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnls1FieldUpdate" runat="server" 
                 UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table class="FillInGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtS1ExpDate" runat="server" Width="67px" TabIndex="14"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdS1ExpDate" runat="server" 
                         ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.png" TabIndex="15" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender6" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtS1ExpDate" PopupButtonID="cmdS1ExpDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboS1ExpenseItem" runat="server" Width="200px" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="cboS1ExpenseItem_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="16">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtS1ExpAmt" runat="server" Width="78px" ontextchanged="txtS1ExpAmt_TextChanged" TabIndex="18" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtS1ExpGST" runat="server" Width="78px" TabIndex="19"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtS1ExpOC" runat="server" Width="78px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtS1ExpOC_TextChanged" TabIndex="20" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdAddSection1Exp" runat="server" Text="Add" Width="80px" 
                        onclick="cmdAddSection1Exp_Click" TabIndex="21" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="HdrGnrl tRt" style="width:105px;">Sub item</td>
                            <td style="width:220px;">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboS1ExpenseSubItem" runat="server" Width="200px" 
                                    TabIndex="17">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:85px;"></td>
                            <td style="width:85px;"></td>
                            <td style="width:85px;"></td>
                            <td style="width:100px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtS1ExpAmt" EventName="TextChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtS1ExpOC" EventName="TextChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cboS1ExpenseItem" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender4" TargetControlID="pnls1FieldUpdate" runat="server">
    <Animations>
        <OnUpdating>
            <Sequence>
                <FadeOut AnimationTarget="pnlExpense" minimumOpacity=".2" />
            </Sequence>
        </OnUpdating>
        <OnUpdated>
            <Sequence>
                <FadeIn AnimationTarget="pnlExpense" minimumOpacity=".2" />
            </Sequence>
        </OnUpdated>
    </Animations>
</asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

Why are all of the updatepanels updating when they shouldnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the code you post, there is only one `UpdatePanel`.

However, please note than the **[ChildrenAsTriggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx)** is set to `true` by default, so a `AsyncPostBackTrigger` will be added automatically for every control that is inside the `UpdatePanel`. So first thing I would try is to set it to `false` :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnls1FieldUpdate" 
                 runat="server" 
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
```

Comment: It is wierd, what I am experiencing is this, after the updatepanel in question is updated, the other updatepanels slowwwwwly update themselves. I have ChidrenAsTriggers = false and UpdateMode = conditional on all of them as well

Comment: the way the page is setup there is a lot of code, I wish I could change it but the client wants to keep it as is for now

Comment: There must be an interaction that triggers the update in the others panels. Since you cannot post the whole code for analysis, the easiest way is to comment out part of it and then re-enable it piece per piece to find the problem.

Comment: I decided to take out the triggers for one of the panels to see if that helped but it is still triggering an update on that panel, I also took the code behind out. I wonder if maybe the control is screwed up

Comment: I realized that the panels where not being updated, it was the update panel animation that was firing instead. Is that an usual occurance?