# issue while using 2 UpdatePanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 UpdatePanels  the 1st one has  a button and the 2nd has a repeater , i don't know why when  i click on find,  the repeater doesn't change even if the datasource change after the click .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnl" runat="server" >
 <ContentTemplate>
.
.

<asp:Button ID="btnfind" runat="server" Text="Find "  OnClick="btnfind_Click" />

<ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnfind" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems"  EnableViewState="false">
...
</asp:Repeater>
             </div></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: They're two different update panels. They don't refresh at the same time or communicate to each other. Move the button outside of its update panel.

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087724/asp-net-multiple-update-panels-updating-when-they-are-not-supposed-to